# Content included from pagination

Tags: shortcode, pagination

I appreciate if someone can help me to explain why my post content shows below the pagination even though I echo the title only.

I call this code via shortcode.

INPUT:

```
// the query to set the posts per page to 3
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 3, 'paged' => $paged );
query_posts($args); 

if ( have_posts() ) : 

    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

        echo "<h2><a href='".get_the_permalink()."'>".get_the_title()."</a></h2>";

    endwhile; 

    the_posts_pagination( array(
            'mid_size' => 2,
            'prev_text' => __( 'Previous page', 'findarch' ),
            'next_text' => __( 'Next page', 'findarch' ),
            'screen_reader_text'    => __('navigation','findarch')
            ) );

else : 
    echo "NOT FOUND.";
endif; 

wp_reset_postdata();
```

OUTPUT:

```
43e
Hello world!
navigation
Previous page 1 2 3 4 

asdasd

dsad

as

das

d

asd
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't SHOUT with caps-lock. Note that `query_posts()` is no longer recommended. Also note that if you're using shortcode, it must **return** the output, not echo it.

Comment: please try this code :<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'paged' => $paged );
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title() ?></h2>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<!-- then the pagination links -->
<?php next_posts_link( '&larr; Older posts', $wp_query ->max_num_pages); ?>
<?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts &rarr;' ); ?>

Comment: Sorry for the caps, some of the page i viewed are using this query thats why im not aware... please can you help me

Comment: Let me run it. thanks vikran i'll let you know if it works.

Comment: Sir. Vikran  it loop the output multiple times.. i also use this method a few days ago ..  does the shortcode affect the outcome ...

Comment: Shortcodes must return their output. Start with a simple example and then expand it.

Comment: Hi sir Birgire i able to output now the data. but the thing is .. when i tried to return the data it use LIFO instead of FIFO ... i mean ... instead of showing the list of post it will show first the paginagination

Comment: I'll see if i can use css to correct the output